# Fetch even numbered records from employees table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I came across a MySQL problem through this [link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/subquery-exercises/write-a-query-to-fetch-even-numbered-records-from-employees-table.php/%22link%22). After reading the answer below (also can be found in the link), I still didn't get it. Could someone explain the steps for me, especially the subquery `(SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i, employee_id FROM employees)`? Thanks in advance!

**Problem:**

Fetch even numbered records from employees table.

**Answer:**

```
SET @i = 0; 

SELECT i, employee_id

FROM (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i, employee_id FROM employees) a 

WHERE MOD(a.i, 2) = 0;
```

Comment: This fetches 'alternate' records in an indeterminate manner, i.e. half the dataset. They're not 'even-numbered' in any meaningful sense - although they may happen to be!

Comment: I guess sloppy answers such as this (being presented as somehow canonical) explains in part why that site is discouraged as a resource on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get even numbered employee ids, all this is unnecessary

```
SELECT employee_id FROM employees
WHERE employee_id%2 = 0;
```

What the above code does is asign arbitary numbers to each employee. That's what the subquery does

```
(SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i, employee_id FROM employees)
```

Starts from zero, uses a counter that increments by one for each row. But as @strawberry has pointed out in the comments, this really doesn't have any purpose or meaning here. Better to use employee_id (unless of course you have a wierd situation where most of the employees have either an odd or an even number instead of an equal distribution)

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: Glad to have helped. All the best with your project.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i, employee_id FROM employees)
> ```

This increments the value of `i` variable for each row fetched (could be any row as there is no order provided here). So, the value of `i` will have no meaning whatsoever.

When you say even numbered rows, there must be some order for numbering. I am assuming employee_id in ascending order here.

Using user variables in a single query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        e.*, @rn:=IF(@rn IS NULL, 1, @rn + 1) rn
    FROM
        employees e
    ORDER BY employee_id) t
WHERE
    rn % 2 = 0;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question

Comment: Thank you very much! I just saw the updates, but it helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For Print Even Row From Table

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE MOD (Employee_id,2)=0;
```

For Print Odd Row From Table

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE MOD (Employee_id,2)<>0
```